# Can I get more amps out of my wind turbine?

Tags: amplifier

I purchased a no name brand wind turbine that's capable of up 52VDC, 400 Watt. The use of a small space heater (1500W), lights, and a TV drains my two automotive batteries below 12volts in under an hour and a half. My wind turbine is unable to keep up with my energy demand. I have tried current step up gadgets that failed, simply quit. I am a novice with electrical components and electricity. Is it possible to get more amps out of my system?
Regards!

Comment: 1. Try to understand basic physics, as is written below from Olin.
2. Consider solving your problem with buying additional +3 (for only powering heater) and maybe +1 or +2 more for TV and lights.

Comment: You should get the wind speed data for your location and predict the annual output of your turbine in kWh over the year and look at your daily needs and work out how to deal with the shortfall. A windturbine does not provide full power unless the wind is at a sufficient speed.

Comment: Yes you can indeed get much more amps if you convert the 52VDC to AC and then use step down transformer. Is your question get more amps or get more power?

Comment: Automotive batteries aren't really designed to supply a lot of constant power, their more for a lot of power in a short amount of time ie when engaging the starter on your car. Deep cycle batteries, boat/marine are this type are better suited for wind/solar storage.

Answer (score 5):

You can't cheat basic physics.

> wind turbine ... 400 Watt.

> heater (1500W), lights, and a TV drains my ... batteries

What did you expect!?  Seriously, this is *really basic* physics.

If every day you put 4 eggs in the fridge, but I take out 15, pretty soon you're going to run out of eggs.

Power (energy per time) is one of those things that is conserved.  You can't make more, just convert it from one form to another.  You are starting with 400 W.  You can't magically make more.  You can change the current x voltage tradeoff, but you can't change the current x voltage product since that is the power.

> Is it possible to get more amps out of my system?

Yes, but that won't do you any good.  It's more *Watts* that you need, but it's not possible to get more of those out of your system.

So basically, your 400 W turbine is insufficient to run your 1500 W heater and other appliances.  This can't be fixed with any amount of conversion.

Comment: Maybe he should consider buying additional 3 or 4 more wind turbines and placing them somewhere close to the 1st.

Comment: @Jakey: I have no need for additional turbines as I'm not the one with the problem.  You should suggest that to the OP, not me.

Comment: I added that to Your answer, because I thought You might add that to the bottom line of Your answer. But hey, who am I here to think?

Comment: Maybe 1500W is the peak power, while average is just 200W

Comment: Could be a nice topic to discuss: energy conversion and storage

Comment: Got it. So regardless off the peaking voltage I'll never be able to exceed a demand of 400watt?

Comment: Is there a way to divert excess energy created by higher wind and store it for back up source?

Comment: "Is there a way to divert excess energy created by higher wind and store it for back up source?" Sigh. Yes. That's what your batteries are for. Use the turbine to charge the batteries when the heater isn't working. Of course, since you discharge the batteries in 1.5 hours, this isn't going to help much.

Comment: You can build a mechanical accumulator, similar to the one that is used at London Tower Bridge, but of course smaller.

Answer (score 0):

400W is the power of the turbine... and the turbine is used to charge the batteries... not to power the appliances!!!

> space heater (1500W), lights, and a TV drains my two **automotive batteries** below 12volts in under an hour and a half.

you should consider buying more batteries to store more <del>Watts</del> energy...

Comment: With an adequate turbine and generator it would be possible to charge batteries and power the appliances. (This is how your car's generator is used.) Batteries don't store watts (power); they store *energy* measured in Wh or joules. Units matter.

Comment: @transistor: yes... Units matter...